# Iterate through databound listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

My listbox is getting its items from a sql database and I'm trying to loop through it and perform an action based on a certain condition. I've done this before but not when it was attached to a db. This is the code I'm using (that doesnt work):

```
foreach (object o in arrList)
{
    foreach (ListItem i in lstInstructors.Items)
    {
        if (i.Text == o.ToString())
        i.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

While I'm debugging im getting null as `ListItem i`, and I'm guessing thats because there's no static items added, so what would be the right call to get the databound items instead of using `lstInstructors.Items`?

Comment: In what method are you doing this?

Comment: its part of its own function being called from Page_Load

Comment: move it to the `ItemDataBound` event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are doing this in the DataBound event:

```
protected void lstInstructors_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (object o in arrList)
    {
        foreach (ListItem i in lstInstructors.Items)
        {
            if (i.Text == o.ToString())
                i.Selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This will ensure that any items that need to be bound are in fact bound when the method runs.

Comment: Awesome. It worked! Thanks a bunch! It sucks I have to wait 7 minutes just to mark your answer correct though

Comment: @mobile one more thing: if you are sure there is only going to be one match, put a `break;` after the `i.Selected = true;`  That way, once it has found a match, it won't compare the rest of the items.

Comment: oops. i actually used it in similar methods as well. Somehow skipped it on this one. Thanks